# Crawling website using selenium in firefox with python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write the simple crawling program to craw the "http://fortune.com/fortune500/", and want to get the value of `<option value = "...">...</option>`, but when using  webelement.text to get the content with tag name("option"), nothing displayed. I wonder why? And who can solve this problem for me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re


#-----------selenium part(ignored)----------------#

browser = webdriver.Chrome() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://fortune.com/fortune500/")

time.sleep(1) # Let the page load, will be added to the API

industry_button = browser.find_element_by_name('filters[Industry]')

print industry_button

count = 0;
industry_value = industry_button.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')

for number in industry_value:
    count += 1
    print number
print count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium makes it easy to deal with `select->option` HTML constructions - there is a [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) that provides an easy-to-use interface. For example, `.options` would list all available options. For each option, you can get the `.text` to get the inner HTML or `.get_attribute('value')` to get the value of the `value` attribute.

Also, instead of `time.sleep()`, explicitly wait for the toggle button to appear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://fortune.com/fortune500/")

# toggle
toggle = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "filter-toggle")))
toggle.click()

# get all options
industry_button = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("filters[Industry]"))
for option in industry_button.options:
    print option.text
```

Prints:

```
Industry: Any
Advertising, marketing
Aerospace and Defense
Airlines
Apparel
Automotive Retailing, Services
Beverages
...
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot! It really help me to make it clear the concept of wait and select(); that really helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`.text` returns the `innerHTML` of that element, not the value.   you want to get the `value` attribute.

Probably something around:

```
element.get_attribute('value')
```